# How can I setup a Manage Magazine Subscriptions in CiviMember

Tags: civimember, joomla, developer

I'm new to this CiviCRM and it looks great so far. We are looking to using it in out Magazines. But we need the functions as per blog below. How can we do this? thanks.

https://civicrm.org/blog/johnd/civicrm-manage-magazine-subscriptions

Sorry guys, I did not explain it clearly. Basically We have a lot of magazines published every two months. The way we determine what magazine our subscribers can get is by issue number. For example if a subscriber is entitled 1 year of magazine, we will tag him as issue 110-115 (via custom fields). Now, the problem is these issue numbers are associated with a month and year of publish.

Wow! I'm impress to this community!. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you actually Dutch or is it just a name? In any case, I am Dutch :-) Not sure what you mean by ' how can we do this' . Can you expand on your question as it now looks far too broad to answer in a few lines.

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you explain what you've tried already, what didn't work and why and also give more details about what you mean by managing magazine subscriptions? You have to do your own homework but the community here can help with specific issues if you get stumped.

Comment: would have been nice if Dutch had engaged beyond the initial question. everyone is a volunteer here. acknowledgement helps.

Answer (score 1):

we (Fuzion) worked with John Derry when getting The Monthly going as a Sub on CiviCRM. There was a lot of nuances they needed particularly involving ensuring that Gift Sub reminders went to the original Giftor etc, etc. I think that since that time they have had internal resources to further finesse their subs process in ways that I cannot explain, but potentially someone at The Monthly could.

But in essence yes you can treat a Subscription as a Membership.

If you detail out really clearly what the exact specs are you need then folk may be able to volunarily help you assess how to achieve this in CiviCRM or you can reach out to one of the Partners for professional advise and support (and customisations/extensions if required).

NOTE: The OP referred to Joomla, for readers who are using Drupal CMS, there are also significant workarounds that can be achieved with either Drupal Webforms or with CiviCRM Entity in terms of finessing the subscription process for the user.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm working on a new site now for a magazine publisher, and have reached the same conclusion: subscription = membership. Wondering if any extensions or other learning came out of the work with The Monthly that might be of value on my project?

Comment: Hi Graham - would be happy to share my learnings via PM on MatterMost if you want. We have another magazine client we have worked with for last 6 or so years. The simple logic of 'membership = subscription' is not problematic, the hard bits are when subscriptions including group subscriptions with varying prices etc.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I'll ping you via Mattermost.